# ActiveAdmin: Update another model after create/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So what I am trying to do is this. I currently have a piece of equipment that has many parts on it. I also have an inventory of parts. What I am looking to do is when you add a part to the equipment, it removes it from the inventory. I currently have the parts attaching to the equipment but not sure how to decrease the quantity. Here are the admin models for part and equipment.

**equipment.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Equipment do
    permit_params :name, :description, :status, :manufacturer_id, :serial, :category_id, :location_id, part_ids: []
    config.per_page = 5

    filter :status, as: :select, collection: proc { Equipment::STATUS }
    filter :category, as: :select, collection: proc { Category.all.where('category_id > ?', 0) }

    index do
        column("Name", :sortable => :id) {|equipment| link_to "#{equipment.name} ", equipment_path(equipment) }
        column("Status")    {|item| status_tag(item.status, 
            if item.status == 'online'
                :green
            else
                :red
            end
        )}
        column :manufacturer
        column :serial
        column :category_id
        column :location_id
        actions
    end

    show do |equipment|
        attributes_table do
            row :name
            row :description do |equipment_item|
                raw(equipment_item.description) 
            end
            row :location
            row :status
            row :serial
            row :category
            row :manufacturer
        end

        panel "Parts List" do
            table_for equipment.parts do |parts|
                column("Name", :sortable => :id) {|part| link_to "#{part.name} ", part_path(part) }
                column :sku
                column :location
                column :department
                column("Quantity In Stock", :qty)
            end
        end

        active_admin_comments
    end

    form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name, label: "Equipment Name"
          f.input :description, label: "Equipment Description", as: :html_editor
          f.input :serial, label: "Serial"
          f.input :status, :label => 'Status', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, collection: Equipment::STATUS if current_user.role == 'admin'
          f.input :manufacturer_id, :label => 'Manufacturer', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Manufacturer.all.map{|m| ["#{m.name}", m.id]}
          f.input :location_id, :label => 'Location', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Location.all.map{|l| ["#{l.name}", l.id]}
          f.input :category_id, :label => 'Category', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Category.all.map{|c| ["#{c.name}", c.id]}
          f.input :parts, :label => 'Parts', :as => :select2_multiple, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Part.all.map{|c| ["#{c.name}", c.id]}
        end
        f.actions
    end

end
```

**part.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Part do
    permit_params :username, :name, :description, :sku, :part_url, :qty, 
                  :attachment, :location_id, :department_id, :remove_attachment, :_wysihtml5_mode

    filter :name
    filter :location
    filter :department

    scope :all, :default => true

    index do
        column("Name", :sortable => :id) {|part| link_to "#{part.name} ", part_path(part) }
        column :sku do |part|
            best_in_place part, :sku, as: :input
        end
        column :qty do |part|
            best_in_place part, :qty, as: :input,
                                :place_holder => "Click To Edit",
                                :html_attrs => { :style => 'width:30%' }
        end
        column :location
        column :department
    end

    show do |parts|
        attributes_table do
            row :name
            row :description do |part|
                raw(part.description) 
            end
            row :location
            row :department
            row :sku
            row :qty
            row("Attached Documents", :sortable => :id) {|part| link_to "#{part.attachment_identifier} ", part.attachment_url }
            row("Part URL", :sortable => :id) {|part| link_to "#{part.part_url} ", part.part_url }
        end
        active_admin_comments
    end

    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name, label: "Part Name"
          f.input :description, label: "Part Description", as: :html_editor
          f.input :sku, label: "Part SKU"
          f.input :qty
          f.input :part_url, label: "Part URL"
          f.input :department_id, :label => 'Department', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Department.all.map{|d| ["#{d.name}", d.id]}
          f.input :location_id, :label => 'Location', :as => :select2, :input_html => { :style => 'width:80%' }, :collection => Location.all.map{|l| ["#{l.name}", l.id]}
          f.input :attachment, :as => :file, :hint => "Current Document: " + 
            if f.object.attachment_identifier
                f.object.attachment_identifier
            else
                ""
            end
          f.input :remove_attachment, as: :boolean, required: :false, label: 'Remove Document'
        end
        f.actions
    end
end
```

And here are the models for each

**models/equipment.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: equipment
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string
#  description     :text
#  location_id     :integer
#  status          :string
#  serial          :string
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#  category_id     :integer
#  manufacturer_id :integer
#

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord

    has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :manufacturer

    has_paper_trail

    STATUS = %w[online offline].freeze

    def status?(base_status)
        return false unless status
        STATUS.index(base_status.to_s) <= STATUS.index(status)
    end

    def remove_part_from_equipment
        equipment = Equipment.find(params[:post][:id])
        part = equipment.parts.find(params[:part][:id])

        if part
            equipment.parts.delete(part)
        end
    end
end
```

**models/part.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: parts
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  name          :string
#  description   :text
#  location_id   :integer
#  sku           :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  part_url      :string
#  document      :string
#  attachment    :string
#  department_id :integer
#  qty           :integer
#

class Part < ApplicationRecord

    has_and_belongs_to_many :equipment
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :department

    has_paper_trail

    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use Active Record callbacks  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: I was looking at callbacks but I am stuck figuring out how to handle the multiple part IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a controller in activeadmin.

In part.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Part do
//the customisation of index, show, form
  controller do
    def create
      @part = Part.new(permitted_params[:part])
      // do what you want
      if @part.save
        redirect_to admin_parts_path
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the same for equipment.rb. Hope it helps !