# activeadmin resource(employee) creates multiple profiles(another resource)instead of having has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, activeadmin

## Employee.rb (active admin resource,has_one :profile)

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Employee do
    
      # See permitted parameters documentation:
      # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
      #
     permit_params  :email,:password,:password_confirmation,profile_attributes:[:name,:date_of_birth,:contact,:current_address,:permanent_address]
      # or
      #
      # permit_params do
      #   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
      #   permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create' && current_user.admin?
      #   permitted
      # end
      index do        
        column :email
        column 'Name' do |f|
          f.profile.name     if !f.profile.nil?
        end  
        column 'Birthday' do |f|
          f.profile.date_of_birth     if !f.profile.nil?
        end  
        column 'Contact' do |f|
          f.profile.contact    if !f.profile.nil?
        end  
        column 'Current address' do |f|
          f.profile.current_address    if !f.profile.nil?
        end  
        column 'Permanent Address' do |f|
          f.profile.permanent_address     if !f.profile.nil?
        end
        actions
      end
    
      form do |f|
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        f.inputs "Login Credentials" do
          f.input :email
          f.input :password
          f.input :password_confirmation
        end
        f.actions
      end
    
      show do
        attributes_table do
          row :email
        end
        attributes_table_for employee.profile do 
          row :name
          row :date_of_birth
          row :contact
          row :current_address
          row :permanent_address
        end  
      end  
    end
```

## profile.rb (Activeadmin resource,belongs_to:employee)

This is getting created multiple times

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Profile do
          permit_params :name, :date_of_birth, :contact, :employee_id, :current_address, :permanent_address
      form do |f|
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        f.inputs "Employee Profile" do
          f.input :employee 
          f.input :name
          f.input :date_of_birth, as: :datepicker
          f.input :contact
          f.input :current_address
          f.input :permanent_address
        end 
        f.actions 
      end
    
      show do
        attributes_table do
          row :name
          row :date_of_birth
          row :contact
          row :current_address
          row :permanent_address
        end   
      end
    end
```

They both are activeadmin resource.How can i restrict it to one profile per employee.

Comment: Do you want to have one page for both models ? I don't understand your question

Comment: All i need is once a profile is created for employee,the employee id should be removed from the dropdown list of add profile page.

Comment: See my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962115/activeadmin-update-another-model-after-create-update/40057171#40057171 . You can create a controller in activeadmin and do whatever you want

Comment: Nope,not the answer to my question,thank you anyways